# Why two r.v. are independent if only if the distribution of the random vector is the product?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis

I need to show that random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent iff the distribution of the random vector $(X,Y)$ is $\mathbb{P}_X \otimes \mathbb{P}_Y$. Consequently, the distribution of the sum of two independent random variables is the convolution of their distribution:
$$
\mathbb{P}_{X+Y} = \mathbb{P}_X*\mathbb{P}_Y.
$$

$\textbf{Definition 1 (Transport of the measure)}$: Suppose that $f$ is a measurable map from $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ to $(\Omega',\mathcal{F}',\mu_f)$ satisfying $\mu_f(A)=\mu(f^{-1}(A))=\mu(f\in A)$. It is called the transport of the measure $\mu$ via $f$.

$\textbf{Definition 2 (distribution)}$: Let $\mu$ is a probability measure. $f$ is a measurable map from $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ to $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{P}_f)$ satisfying $\mathbb{P}_f(A)=\mathbb{P}(f^{-1}(A))=\mathbb{P}(f\in A)$. Thus $\mathbb{P}_f$ is called the distribution of $f$.

$\textbf{Definition 3 (Convolution of two finite measures)}:$ Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two finite measures on $\mathbb{R}$.  Consider the product measure $\mu \otimes \nu$ on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, and a measureable map f :$\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(s,t)=s+t$.
The convolution $\mu *\nu$ of $\mu$ with $\nu$ is defined as the transport of $\mu \otimes \nu$ via $f$.
Thus, $\mu*\nu$ is a bounded measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and ,by the change of variables formula,
$$ \int g d(\mu*\nu) = \int \int g(s+t)\mu (ds) \nu (dt).$$
We have $\mu *\nu (\mathbb{R}) =  \mu \otimes \nu (\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})=\mu(\mathbb{R})\nu(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ and $Y$ are independent means $P(X \in A, Y \in B) = P(X \in A)P(Y \in B)$ for all measurable sets $A, B$. This can be phrased as $P_{X, Y}(A \times B) = (P_X \otimes P_Y)(A \times B)$. So obviously $P_{X, Y} = P_X \otimes P_Y$ implies $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Conversely, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then a routine application of the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem shows that $P_{X, Y}(E) = (P_X \otimes P_Y)(E)$ for all measurable $E$.

Comment: Thanks your answer!